# syntax error : unexpected type 'P_HDR'

Tags: c++, syntax

I'm a newbie at C++ and I'm trying to compile this application however I'm getting an error: 'syntax error : unexpected type 'P_HDR'. Let me know if you need more code, all of it can be seen at http://www.binarytides.com/blog/raw-sockets-packets-with-winpcap/

```
pseudo_header.source_address = inet_addr("1.2.3.4"); //forge it >:) srcip.s_addr; 
pseudo_header.dest_address = inet_addr("203.200.89.200");
pseudo_header.placeholder = 0;
pseudo_header.protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
pseudo_header.tcp_length = htons(sizeof(TCP_HDR) + strlen(dump));
memcpy(&pseudo_header.tcp , tcphdr , sizeof TCP_HDR);

unsigned char *seudo;
    seudo = new unsigned char(sizeof P_HDR + strlen(dump));
memcpy(seudo, &pseudo_header, sizeof P_HDR);
memcpy(seudo + sizeof P_HDR , data , strlen(dump));
```

This line is the error

seudo = new unsigned char(sizeof P_HDR + strlen(dump));

Answer (score 2):

Might it be that you missed "TC" before "P_HDR"?

Comment: And of course, @retired-ninja is right: brackets (parentheses) needed around types

Comment: and P_HDR is a type (by looking at the source)

Comment: In my experience, knowing the rule is good, but always using parentheses is better because it doesn't cause a line of freaked out people at your desk that you need to explain it to.  :)